# My application was rejected by samsung app store 3 times

Tags: samsung-mobile, android

My application was rejected by samsung app store 3 times. But every time i got reason for rejection is "Application is terminated or initialized after releasing HOLD mode". But my application was running in my device without any problem. Can you please tell me any suggestions to conform my application.

Here is my application link on play store.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dumadugames.darkrunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When playing your game and hold down the power button, the game should no longer be initialized. So probable pause the game and sound in 'onPause()'

Check number 3 in this list: [Samsung developer app certification](http://developer.samsung.com/distribute/app-certification/top-10-failures-and-tips)